# Recursively find height of tree/ deepest node

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Can anyone help walk me through finding the height of a tree by using a recursive depth first search? i.e find the deepest branch node?
Thanks

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Hint: height of a tree is `h(T) = max(h(T.left), h(T.right)) + 1`

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz you should mention it's valid only for binary trees.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: true, but for arbitrary tree it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

**dfs( v )**:
**1.** visited[ v ] = true 
**2.** max_child_depth = 0 
**3. for each** u s.t. there's edge (v,u) 
        **if** not visited[ u ]
        **then** max_child_depth = max( max_child_depth, dfs( u )) 
**4. return** max_child_depth + 1

Comment: If this a tree-it's not a binary tree- is it necessary to keep track of what nodes have been visited?

Comment: If it's oriented or it's either way known for each vertex who are it's children and who is parent - no. But if no, you have to keep it to avoid going back to parent node